# statistical anomaly?

Tags: statistics, correlation

I wrote some code that processes 135,000 books.  I just got word from my retailer that 983 books seem to have an issue and is blaming my code for "screwing up" his inventory.  I have a friend on the inside that says that there has been an on going issue with his inventory and it doesnt look to be me.

I'm thinking that if the issue was my code, more than .73% (983/135,000) of the data would be affected.  How do I reply to him in mathematical terms to disprove his theory that it was my code?

Comment: There is certainly no proof that your code does work just because it works most of the time. Some bugs have infrequent occurences. Even without resorting to maths, there is no way you can disprove your retailer's theory based on statistics alone. That's just plain aristotelician logic to me.

Comment: Not sure what "aristotelician logic" is, but if you have a better way to create proof, I am all ears.

Comment: Excuse my French. I meant Aristotelian logic. If you want a proof, you will need to analyze what went wrong with the 0.73% of your records and see if your code is at fault.

Comment: Ok, so forgo stats.  Having issues in less than 1% of a dataset seems very strange to me.  One would think that this would be more persistent through the code.  Thoughts on how to prove?

Comment: Take a sample of "wrong" records and see how your code processes them.

Comment: He wont allow me access to them, nor will he provide them.  Without data in hand, I have no way to disproving him.  I was hoping statistic would help and I could bring it to his manager.  I need something to prove that his processing is the information.

Comment: @Dan, _take_ it to his manager. The fact that he's refusing to show you why he thinks they're wrong means the relationship is already broken. You cannot fix what you cannot analyse.

Comment: I agree, however my manager would like the full amount paid and is asking me to disprove him

Comment: Then you need to educate _your_ manager. Let's say I wrote a program for Bob that added one to a particular database column. Then Bob comes back to say it added two to some of them. I cannot confirm/disprove that in _any_ way unless Bob and I cooperate somehow. All I can do is state that it worked for _all_ my test data and Bob needs to show me it failing so I can analyse where the issue lies. If he's not _willing_ to do that, the fault is with him rather than me, regardless of my code quality. In other words, the problem is _not_ that my code failed, it's that Bob is blocking the solution.

Comment: I have asked my manager to talk to the owner to try and provide the evidence.  It's my belief that the issue already existed and by my code updating the files, it's exposed his data issues.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe exactly 983 books have a cedilla. Or Japanese characters. Or diphthongs.

I don't think there's any way you can use statistics here that won't cause statisticians to cringe.

Why don't you just offer a 0.73% discount to your fee, based on the outcome? :-)

Or, offer to fix the problem, meaning that they'll have to provide the information as to *why* they think they're screwed up.

In other words, make them specify what "screwed up" actually means. Do they not open in the reader? Do they open but characters or formatting are incorrect? Do they "brick" the reading devices?

Without real information, there's little you can do.

Comment: I agree.  They need to either provide the evidence and have us fix the issue or fix the data themselves if they're unwilling to work with us.